# Unexpected identifier Syntax Error when using mysql and bcryptjs

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, bcrypt

I'm using Mysql in my Express app
i hashed users pass using bcryptjs in mysql db and its fine.
using this code :

```js
// register
router.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
  const hashed = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.pass, 10);
  const user = {
    uname: req.body.uname,
    phone: req.body.phone,
    pass: hashed
  };
  let sql = "INSERT INTO user SET ? ";
  db.query(sql, user, (err, result) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(`${user.uname} INSERTED INTO users`);
  });
});
// GET USERS
router.get("/users", (req, res) => {
  db.query("SELECT * FROM user", (err, results) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.send(err);
    } else {
      return res.json({
        data: results
      });
    }
  });
});
```

but when i want to log in users and let bcrypt compare requested pass with user pass it will give me this err : 
`SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`

And this is what i tried :

```js
// loggin
router.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
  var username = req.body.uname;
  var password = req.body.pass;
  db.query(
    "SELECT pass FROM user WHERE uname = ?",
    [username],
    (err, result, fields) => {
      try {
        if (await bcrypt.compare(password, result)) {
          console.log('Success')
        }
      } catch {
        console.log('catched')
      }
    }
  );
});
```

Comment: The callback function for `db.query()` is not async, you can't use `await` in it.

Comment: @Barmar true :) but now the error is different : `Error: Illegal arguments: string, object `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The only one reason** why you got some error, it's because you're using `await` in a function without `async`

‍ **You can use** this code below :

```js
router.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
  var username = req.body.uname;
  var password = req.body.pass;
  db.query(
    "SELECT pass FROM user WHERE uname = ?",
    [username],
    async (err, result, fields) => {
      try {
        // if you're using mysql2, don't forget to change `result` with `result[0].pass`.
        // you can console.log(result) to see where is the field of your password plain text
        const isPassword = await bcrypt.compare(password, result);
        console.log(isPassword); // true
      } catch(ex) {
        console.log(ex); // false
      }
    }
  );
});
```

I hope it's can help you .

Comment: THANKS !!! that error gone, but i have this now: `Error: Illegal arguments: string, object `

Comment: You can see my `comments` in the code of my answer. Make sure you're using your `password` from database as `result` or `result[0].pass`. Please `console.log` it first. Where is the plain text of your password